Can the coroutine launched through runBlocking be executed on 2 or more threads?
I have this runBlocking code and I wanted to know if its guaranteed that coroutine launched through runBlocking will always execute on the same thread (i.e. thread on which runBlocking started executing) ?
1st println will show say Thread t1. But after the suspend function delay is executed, I want to know will this coroutine resume in same Thread t1 or is it possible to be executed on different thread Thread t2 ? This is because a coroutine can be executed on 2 or more threads so the coroutine created by runBlocking can execute on thread t1 and get suspended on delay() and resume on different thread t2.
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { // Thread t1
  println("runBlocking start: ${Thread.currentThread().name}") // Thread t1

  delay(3000)

  println("runBlocking end: ${Thread.currentThread().name}") // is it necessary to be t1 ?
}

The output I am getting every time is(but I feel that in 2nd line of output it could also have been DefaultDispatcher-worker-2):--

runBlocking start: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1


runBlocking end: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1


Yes, as long as you specify a multi-threaded dispatcher like Dispatchers.Default.
Try launching a new coroutine or two inside runBlocking:
fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
  log("runBlocking start")
  async { delay(50) }.await()
  log("runBlocking end")
}

Eventually, different threads will be printed:
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1] runBlocking start
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#1] runBlocking end


@jan-itor answer is correct and solved my query.
Although using DefaultDispatcher is printing same thread every time for my PC.
I created my own custom CorotuineDispatcher to demonstrate that this coroutine might also get executed on 2 different threads.
fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100).asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
  log("runBlocking start") // [pool-1-thread-1] runBlocking start
  async { delay(500) }.await()
  log("runBlocking end") //[pool-1-thread-4] runBlocking end
}


On my machine, @jan-itor answer works some of the time, but it mostly logs both lines on the same thread. Your code shows the logs on different threads every single time. Also, with your code, you don't need to call async: just calling delay will work too. However, note that your program doesn't terminate. You need to shut down the executor at the end.

@k314159 Thanks for clarity, Yes its a good practice to close the custom dispatcher. I forgot to do that.

Unlike the answer by @jan-itor, you don't need to wrap the delay call in async. If you call runBlocking in two separate threads, you can see the effect of the delay call alone:
fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")

fun main() {
    repeat(2) { rep ->
        thread {
            runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
                log("$rep: runBlocking start")
                delay(50)
                log("$rep: runBlocking end")
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] 1: runBlocking start
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] 0: runBlocking start
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] 1: runBlocking end
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] 0: runBlocking end

This shows that in the runBlocking call of rep 1 started in thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 and finished in thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-2, while in rep 0 it was the opposite.
You can see this more clearly if you run with the -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug VM option:
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#2] 1: runBlocking start
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1] 0: runBlocking start
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 @coroutine#1] 0: runBlocking end
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2] 1: runBlocking end

